# Cannot add developer to AppStore Connect

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

When I try add invite a developer in Users section of AppStore Connect, I get the error "There are one or more validation errors below."

[image: Error displayed on AppStore Connect]

When I inspect the request, I found the actual error to be: "Individual can't have provisioning privilege."

[image: Actual error]

Any help in resolving this issue is appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Managed to add an account with minor roles (sales, ...) but can't ad it as Developer. Seems to be an Apple side issue.

Comment: Not having any issues here. Could you try a different browser and/or use incognito mode? Does the email contain a "+", e.g. test+dev@gmail.com Are you using a personal dev account or a company one?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, it seems this started a couple of days ago.

Comment: @Max I'm trying to add me as a developer to an 'individual/sole trader' apple developer account (this used to work before)

Comment: It's still working for me. Just tried with a personal account. I would recommend contacting Developer Support: https://developer.apple.com/contact/